# How to upload large files in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Using the default FileField, an upload from the admin page for a model will only be successful if the given image file is very small. Otherwise an error will be thrown:

> Using the URLconf defined in astrobanana.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>   1. ^$ [name='index']
>   2. ^(?P\d+)/$ [name='comic']
>   ... etc etc ...
>
> The current URL, 500.shtml, didn't match any of these.

Note that I once used ImageField, but in an attempt to solve the problem, I switched to using FileField, thinking that perhaps django was prohibiting an image from being uploaded because it did not read it as an image.

Needless to say, I am confused.  Small images work and large images throw a cryptic error. Everything relevant in settings.py seems to be defined and proper, especially seeing as small images upload properly.  However, here are my current relevant settings for reference.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/astroban/public_html/astrobanana/media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://astrobanana.com/media/'
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = (
        'django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
        'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler',
        )

FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = None
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = None
```

In addition, here is the code for the model in question:

```
    from django.db import models

    class ComicPost(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        comic = models.FileField(upload_to='comics/')
        hovertext = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True,null=True)
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
        hits = models.IntegerField(editable=False,default=0)
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not self.id:
                i = ComicPost.objects.all().order_by('-id')[0]
                self.id = i.id+1
            super(ComicPost, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title
        class Meta:
            ordering = ('-timestamp',)
```

... And here is the admin.py:

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from astrobanana.comic.models import ComicPost

    class ComicPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('title','timestamp','hits')

    admin.site.register(ComicPost,ComicPostAdmin)
```

Everything seems pretty standard.  What's wrong with any of this?  Any help is appreciated I've racked my brains.

Comment: Why do you have FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = None? Large uploads (currently > 2621440 bytes) will have to be stored on disk while processing the request. If it cannot store the upload, you will have an error.